# the risks to plot travel (comprehension)

Tags: comprehension

Source: [*Escaped from Eritrea, refugee route leads to Europe*](http://news.yahoo.com/escaped-eritrea-refugee-route-leads-europe-072553555.html) (news article)

Example:

> New arrivals in the camp dismiss **the risks** of ruthless people smugglers and treacherous waters **to plot travel** onwards north to Sudan, and then on to Europe.

So, what this in essence says is that the arrivals dismiss the risks of blah, blah, blah to plot travel to Europe that can be quite dangerous due to a lot of bad things that may happen en route. The thing that I don't understand, however, is how the mere act of plotting your travel route can be dangerous or risky per se? The travel, however, can be. Do you think this is a semantic error or something of that nature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment you quoted essentially says that the "New arrivals" plot their travel without taking those risks into consideration.

One can dismiss "the risks" while ***doing*** something, or one can dismiss the risks ***of*** doing something while ***planning*** doing that something, too.